# Lowest-level way to observe object changes

Tags: javascript, node.js

A real-time app that must broadcast a big object to all clients as soon as it changes.

**What is the the lowest-level way to observe any change in a Node.JS object?**

For example, given the object:

```
var obj = {
  num: 3,
  deep: {
      num: 5
  }
}
```

A function would be triggered after calling any of these:

- `obj.num = 10;`
- `obj.num.deep.num = 10;`
- `obj.num.deep = undefined;`
- And so on...

**Is it possible? How?**

---

I **can't** use:

- [WatchJS](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS): Because it uses polling.
- Getters/setters: Because the object structure is not known.

Comment: What changes it?

Comment: @Ryan Hard to explain, didn't do so to keep the question simple. Here it is: A convolutional neural network that may change any part of `obj` at any time. Socket.on('connect') also already trigger this function when a new user connects.

Comment: Whenever it changes `obj`, fire an event, then.

Comment: I don't think there are easily hookup-able methods in this Conv. N.N. In fact it may attempt to do something like `obj.abc.qwe = 10` and fail, or `obj.num = 10` and actually change the value. It may also create new properties `obj.temp = 98`.

Comment: Are you using some kind of package, and that’s why you can’t hook into it?

Comment: @Ryan no libraries (probably I should). I know that what you say is possible but that would add a significant overhead to the algorithm writing method. I would also like to keep stuff separated (Conv. N.N. / watcher) because the architecture may change at any time (currently using a Hopfield Network, see http://www.asimovinstitute.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/neuralnetworks.png)

Comment: It’s extremely likely to be the best way. You might not have to put much in – just emit the key whenever you make a successful write. Or maybe you do, but… that’s my suggestion.

Comment: Why do you think you can't use getters? They work fine with unknown object structures (just not with dynamically changing structures).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, this should be doable by exposing a proxy of your object instead of the object itself.
You could then intercept the setter in the proxy, and trigger an event from there.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy
https://caniuse.com/#feat=proxy

Comment: Thanks!  I already looked into it. However take a look at this: http://thecodebarbarian.com/thoughts-on-es6-proxies-performance. The performance of proxies is not very good.

Comment: @adelriosantiago The performance of observing every change of an object *is* not very good.